# Detect when node hits bottom of screen

Tags: iphone, sdk, sprite-kit

Okay, I am trying to detect when either one of my nodes hit the bottom of the screen. This code yields Game Over every second and floods my console.

```
- (void)updateWithTimeSinceLastUpdate:(CFTimeInterval)timeSinceLast {

    if (self.metalCrate.position.y || self.crate.position.y >= 568) {
        NSLog(@"Game Over.");
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can use a contact delegate to achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is at your if statement. It should be like this

```
 if (self.metalCrate.position.y == SOMETHING || self.crate.position.y >= 568) {
    NSLog(@"Game Over.");
}
```

You need to compare self.metalCrate.position.y to something, otherwise, as long as self.metalCrate.position.y is not nil, your if verification will always be true.

Comment: What should I replace SOMETHING with?

Comment: I want to detect if either the self.metalCrate or the self.crate hits the bottom.

Comment: Then you should do, self.metalCrate.position.y >= 568 || self.crate.postion.y >= 568.

Comment: Oh, that cause actually the bottom of your screen is at coordinate 0, if you are using SpriteKit, then you should do the following,  self.metalCrate.position.y < 0 || self.crate.postion.y < 0

Comment: Thanks. Now I am getting no NSLog entries.

Comment: Well, if thats not what you wanted im not sure what you are asking for, if you explain better i can try to help.

Comment: Okay, I am spawning nodes at the top of the iPhone screen, they fall to the bottom, I want to detect when one of them hits the bottom and if it does, put an entry into NSLog.

Comment: You can try to NSLog("%f / %f\n", self.metalCrate.position.y, self.crate.postion.y) in your update method, then you'll see the objects y position every update. Then you can verify whats the position of it when it hits the bottom and make the right if statement. You will actually see that is near 0, so when your objects y position is less than 0, it means its under the bottom of the screen

Comment: I did that, and positions ranged from 300 to about 500, wasn't too accurate because I have multiple instances of self.crate, etc.

Comment: Thats kind of a bigger problem, if there is anyway i can have access to your code it would be much easier to help. Cause if you have multiple instances of self.crate that can be what messing things up.

Comment: Umm... what is your email?